# How do I sort a flat Json by Date?

Tags: php, json, date, usort

I am pretty new to php and Jsons and I am trying to arrange contents of a Json by date. I know about the usort() function but so far I have been unsuccessful at using it. This is the Json:

```
[{"id":"1","poi_id":"36","date":"1993-05-14","url":"#","p_flag":"0"},{"id":"2","poi_id":"36","date":"2000-05-14","url":"#","p_flag":"0"},{"id":"3","poi_id":"36","date":"1992-05-14","url":"#","p_flag":"0"}]
```

What I have been trying to do is this:

```
function sortByYear($a, $b) {
    $dA = new DateTime($a['date']);
    $dB = new DateTime($b['date']);

    return $dA->format('y') - $dB->format('y');
}
$data=json_decode($unsorted, true);
print_r(usort($data, 'sortByYear'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    $unsorted = '[{"id":"1","poi_id":"36","date":"1993-05-14","url":"#","p_flag":"0"},{"id":"2","poi_id":"36","date":"2000-05-14","url":"#","p_flag":"0"},{"id":"3","poi_id":"36","date":"1992-05-14","url":"#","p_flag":"0"}]';

function sortByYear($a, $b) {
    $dA = new DateTime($a['date']);
    $dB = new DateTime($b['date']);

    return $dA > $dB;
}
$data=json_decode($unsorted, true);
usort($data, 'sortByYear');
print_r($data);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1qAG3N)

A few points:

1. You need to sort by the full year `Y`, not the last twp digits `y`. When you cross over the new millennium you have problems.
2. I used `>` for the comparison. It is clearer what the sort is that way.
3. `usort()` sorts in place so no array is returned. This means you need to call `var_dump()` on the original array, not `usort()`.

Comment: This only sorts by year doesn't it? How do I get it to consider the month and day as well because the result has to be in chronological order

Comment: See my updated code. DateTime objects are comparible which is awesome.