# Sort JSON object by string datetime

Tags: php, json

I have a json object which containing many objects. one of the values is time. The problem is it is a string at the moment. How can i convert this to a date and then sort all the objects by this date and then place it into a new array?

the object

```
$json_string = 'http://95.85.11.40/wordpress/?page_id=20';

$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

This is a example of the value for key time:

```
April 20, 2014 10:13 am
```

Comment: Put it into an array and then sort the array by that value. There's *lots* of examples of that here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Dont i need to change it to a date or something?

Comment: Yes, converting the date to a sortable format will be required but that [can also be found here as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php/23087239#23087239).

Comment: Actually, here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146068/how-do-i-sort-a-flat-json-by-date/23146089#23146089. That's 95% of what you have to do.

Comment: The main problem here is i need to convert this April 20, 2014 10:13 am to something like this i guys 20/04/2014 10:13

Comment: See the first link I posted

Comment: Yes but i need to change this april 20, 2014 10:13 am to something like 20/04/2014 10:13 how can i do this

Comment: You *really* should read that [first link I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php/23087239#23087239)